# How to create new columns based off specific conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe. The index's are represented by an ID and date. The 3 columns I have are cost, revenue, and expenditure.

I want to create 3 new columns based off certain conditions.

1) The first new column I would want to create would be based off the condition, for the 3 most previous dates per ID, if the cost column decreases consistently, label the new row values as 'NEG', if not then label it 'No'.

2) The second column I would want to create would be based off the condition, for the 3 most recent dates, if the revenue column decreases consistently, label the new row values as 'NEG', if not then label it 'No'.

3) The third column I would want to create would be based off the condition, for the 3 most recent dates, if the expenditure column increases consistently, label the new row value as 'POS' or if it stays the same label the new row value as 'STABLE'.

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['001', '002', '003','004'],
                              ['2017-06-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-06-30','2018-12-31','2019-06-30']],
                             names=['ID', 'Date'])
col = ['Cost', 'Revenue','Expenditure']

 dict2 = {'Cost':[12,6,-2,-10,-16,-10,14,12,6,7,4,2,1,4,-4,5,7,9,8,1],
     'Revenue':[14,13,2,1,-6,-10,14,12,6,7,4,2,1,4,-4,5,7,9,18,91],
     'Expenditure':[17,196,20,1,-6,-10,14,12,6,7,4,2,1,4,-4,5,7,9,18,18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict2,idx,col)
```

i have tried creating a function then applying it to my DF but i keep getting errors...

the solution i want to end up with would look like this..

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['001', '002', '003','004'],
                              ['2017-06-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-06-30','2018-12-31','2019-06-30']],
                             names=['ID', 'Date'])
col = ['Cost', 'Revenue','Expenditure', 'Cost Outlook', 'Revenue Outlook', 'Expenditure Outlook']

dict3= {'Cost':  [12,6,-2,-10,-16,
            -10,14,12,6,7,
            4,2,1,4,-4,
            5,7,9,8,1],


    'Cost Outlook':   ['no','no','NEG','NEG','NEG', 
                       'no','no','no','NEG','NEG', 
                       'no','no','NEG','no','no', 
                       'no','no','no','no','NEG'],



    'Revenue':[14,13,2,1,-6,
               -10,14,12,6,7,
               4,2,1,4,-4,
               5,7,9,18,91],

    'Revenue Outlook': ['no','no','NEG','NEG','NEG', 
                        'no','no','no','NEG','NEG', 
                        'no','no','NEG','no','no', 
                        'no','no','no','no','no'],



    'Expenditure':[17,196,1220,1220, -6,
                   -10,14,120,126,129, 
                   4,2,1,4,-4,
                   5,7,9,18,18],


    'Expenditure Outlook':['no','no','POS','POS','no', 
                           'no','no','POS','POS','POS', 
                           'no','no','no','no','no', 
                           'no','no','POS','POS','STABLE']
   }

df_new  = pd.DataFrame(dict3,idx,col)
```

Comment: How the `Expenditure` in `2018-12-31` is stable when the last 3 months are `196, 1220, 1220`? You said based on 3 months, but only last 2 months are equal.

Comment: you are correct, let me edit

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
# update Cost and Revenue Outlooks 
# because they have similar conditions
for col in ['Cost', 'Revenue']:
    groups = df.groupby('ID')

    outlook = f'{col} Outlook'
    df[outlook] = groups[col].diff().lt(0)

    # moved here
    df[outlook] = np.where(groups[outlook].rolling(2).sum().eq(2), 'NEG', 'no')

# update Expenditure Outlook
col = 'Expenditure'
outlook = f'{col} Outlook'
s = df.groupby('ID')[col].diff()

df[outlook] = np.select( (s.eq(0).groupby(level=0).rolling(2).sum().eq(2),
                          s.gt(0).groupby(level=0).rolling(2).sum().eq(2)),
                        ('STABLE', 'POS'), 'no')
```

Comment: is there supposed to be an indent where expenditure starts? also im getting an error for the syntax error for outlook=

Comment: also it isnt repeating it for all the ID's only the last one, any fix for that?

Comment: I messed up copy/paste from different cells. See update.

Comment: it still only does this for 1 id, is there a way to make sure it iterates for each ID?

Comment: What do you mean by *one id*? The point of `groupby` is to handle all id's at once. Did you check the output?

Comment: yes the output only returns 1 id, but i want all ids

Comment: It ran fine on the sample data set. Remember for the actual data set, `print(df)` only prints few first lines of the data frame.

Comment: See the code and output [here](https://repl.it/repls/WorthyJaggedSoftwareagent)

Comment: i will try again, is there a different syntax for f '{col} Outlook' that keeps giving me a syntax error as well

Comment: That only works with Python 3.5+, use `outlook = col + ' Outlook'` instead.

Comment: hey this almost works perfectly but is there a way to account for the order? for example i want it to only produce NEG if if everything before it was actually lower, i.e for Cash if it goes from 8.5 to 9.1 to 6.9 i get a return of NEG

Answer (score 0):

See if this does the job:

```
is_descending = lambda a: np.all(a[:-1] > a[1:])
is_ascending = lambda a: np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:])
df1 = df.reset_index()
df1["CostOutlook"] = df1.groupby("ID").Cost.rolling(3).apply(is_descending).fillna(0).apply(lambda x: "NEG" if x > 0 else "no").to_list()
df1["RevenueOutlook"] = df1.groupby("ID").Revenue.rolling(3).apply(is_descending).fillna(0).apply(lambda x: "NEG" if x > 0 else "no").to_list()
df1["ExpenditureOutlook"] = df1.groupby("ID").Expenditure.rolling(3).apply(is_ascending).fillna(0).apply(lambda x: "POS" if x > 0 else "no").to_list()
df1 = df1.set_index(["ID", "Date"])
```

Note: The requirement for "STABLE" is not handled.

**Edit:**
This is alternative solution:

```
is_descending = lambda a: np.all(a[:-1] > a[1:])
def is_ascending(a):
    if np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:]):
        if a[-1] == a[-2]:
            return 2
        return 1
    return 0

for col in ['Cost', 'Revenue']:
    outlook = df[col].unstack(level="ID").rolling(3).apply(is_descending).fillna(0).replace({0.0:"no", 1.0:"NEG"}).unstack().rename(f"{col} outlook")
    df = df.join(outlook)

col = "Expenditure"
outlook = df[col].unstack(level="ID").rolling(3).apply(is_ascending).fillna(0).replace({0.0:"no", 1.0:"POS", 2.0:"STABLE"}).unstack().rename(f"{col} outlook")
df = df.join(outlook)
```